# How to call phtml file on every page in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to call a phtml file on every page in magento 1 `head section`
is their any way we can perform it in magento 1 ?
I am using a theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add phtml on all pages we can add it using layout

Create:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
   <reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="core/template" name="test.name" template="page/test.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Noe create phtml at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/template/page/test.phtml

```
<?php echo "here"; ?>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: i want to add phtml in Head tag

Comment: You can use `<reference name="head">` instead of `<reference name="before_body_end">`.

Comment: Can we call this phtml file using module ?